# ACL role assignments not showing on screen, but still working

Tags: acl

When I go to civicrm/acl/entityrole it shows no role assignments and says "There are no Role Assignments. You can add one now."

But they exist, have not been deleted and are still working. I can see them in the database table (`select * from civicrm_acl_entity_role;`)

Anyone else have this problem? It looks like a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I saw a second person report the same issue, I suspected a bug, so I successfully replicated the problem on the demo site.  See the [CiviCRM bug reporting](https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting) page.

I determined that this is a side effect of changes made in [CRM-20351](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20351).

Because this seemed like an easy enough bug to fix, I went ahead and did so.  I filed it as [CRM-21076](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21076), and submitted a solution as pull request [#10866](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10866).

It's a [one-line fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10866/files), so feel free to fix manually.  I'm going to argue that this should go into 4.7.24, but 4.7.25 seems almost a certainty.

Comment: You're a star. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same situation after upgrading from 4.7.16 to 4.7.23

The Tabs "Manage Roles" and "Manage ACLs" are showing entries, 
"Assign Users" (= civicrm/acl/entityrole) don't show any entries.

They are still in a database, and if I add a new one, it ends up in the database, but it still don't show up in this view.

Comment: This is very helpful - but since it doesn't answer the question, it should perhaps be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: To be fair, my question was "has anyone seen this"